# Problemas com OPENROWSET no SQL Server 2016 Express (64bit)

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-excel, tsql

Bom dia, estou tentando ler um arquivo Excel .xls pelo driver OLEDB utilizado no SQL Server para integrações com arquivos o Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 no SQL Server 2016 Express (64bit). Utilizando o comando `OPENROWSET` mas estou recebendo o famoso erro:

```
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null).
```

Já executei vários procedimentos relatados em pesquisa mas sem sucesso!

Procedimentos:

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

Selecionando a planilha:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\Underline\Documents\Temp\Publicacao.xls', [Publicação $])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já alterei as permissões na pasta para acesso as contas de Rede e Local:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Baixei e instalei o Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable versão x64, mas nada ainda. Alguém já passou por essa situação? E queira compartilhar um pouco da sua experiência.

Comment: Evandro, você pode transcrever a primeira mensagem de erro, completa? Na imagem ficou truncada  // O nome interno da folha da planilha é "Publicação"? // Observe que ficou um espaço no comando; retire-o: [Publicação$]

Comment: @JoséDiz Primeira linha: `Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error` O nome da folha é Publicação e tem um espaço mesmo, eu recebo essa planilha de um site externo e existe esse espaço na folha tenho que manter.. mas já fiz o teste sem o espaço também.

Comment: Você autenticou na instância usando o método Windows Authentication? Se sim, o usuário não faz parte do grupo `Administrador`?

Comment: @JoséDiz Sim método Windows Authentication e o usuário no grupo Administrador.

Comment: @JoséDiz descobri que o problema está com o arquivo, quando baixo do site externo ele vêm no formato Pagina da Web. Ao abrir o arquivo no Excel ele da a seguinte mensagem `O formato de arquivo e a extensão de 'Publicacao.xls' não correspondem. O arquivo pode estar corrompido ou não ser segura. Não o abra, a menos que confie na fonte. Quer abri-lo mesmo assim?` ao confirmar ele abre em modo de exibição protegido. Tem alguma forma de abrir direto ou converter via código!?

Comment: Eu tenho uma situação semelhante em que recebo planilha no formato HTML e com o arquivo tendo a extensão `.htm`. Renomeio a extensão para `.xls`, abro-a no LibreOffice Calc e salvo no formato CSV. A partir daí é o processo automático de importação de arquivo com formato CSV em conjunto com arquivo de formato. // No seu caso, se todo o processo tem que ser automático, será necessário pesquisar por conversor de html para csv.

Comment: @JoséDiz Eu queria automatizar todo o processo, mas não vejo outra alternativa terei que abrir o arquivo e salvar como para depois selecionar os dados da planilha. :(

Comment: Bom dia, porque você não usa o "bulk insert" do sql, ele é nativo do sql.